# Compare Two Sheets Headers and return mismatching Values in Both

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Sheets NewSheet and Old Sheet their headers (first rows) shoud be identical but actually the are not for example :

[image]

So the code should return in msgbox show mismatch Cell address and cell value in both sheets

Old Sheet Mismatch : Cell C1 Value  C ,
Cell E1 Value  E

NewSheet Mismatch :  Cell D1 Value  F ,
Cell E1 Value  G

I've made alot of trial but all away from the target. Your help is highly appreciated

This is one of the trial adapting code from googling :

```
    Sub HeaderCompare2(ByVal oldWbPath As String, ByVal newWbPath As String)

    Dim wbOld As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
        
    Dim rngOld As Range, rngNew As Range, c As Range, FoundRange As Range

    Dim msg As String
    
    Set wbOld = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=oldWbPath)
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=newWbPath)
    
    Set rng1 = wbOld.Worksheets("TRAIN-D").Range("A1:BP1")
    Set rng2 = wbNew.Worksheets("TRAIN-D").Range("A1:BP1")

    Dim iRow As Integer
    iRow = 1
    
    For Each rng1cell In rng1
        For Each rng2cell In rng2
            If rng1cell <> rng2cell Then
                
                msg = msg & rng1cell
                iRow = iRow + 1
            End If
        Next rng2cell
    Next rng1cell

    MsgBox msg


End Sub
```

The Sheets are in two different workbooks where i pass their path to the function HeaderCompare2

Comment: Why don't you use formulas and/or conditional formatting? If you want to stay with VBA: please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Using VBA to better autmate this task esp. i can run this code from C# app for example. For the trial i got the code from googling and tryed for hours to adapt it to suit my case but result always disappointing.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the code you've tried please.  Even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try this fancy way. It uses only arrays (matching them in different ways) and a single iteration only for the two ways/sheets for returning:

```
Sub MatchHeaders()
 Dim wsOld As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet, lastCol As Long, arrO, arrN, arrMtch, mtch
 
 Set wsOld = ActiveSheet 'use here your Old sheet
 Set wsNew = wsOld.Next  'use here your New sheet (now, this new sheet is after the old one...)
 lastCol = wsOld.cells(1, wsOld.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column 'last header column
 arrO = wsOld.Range("A1", wsOld.cells(1, lastCol)).Value2 place the headers in an array
 With Application
    arrO = .Transpose(.Transpose(arrO)) 'the array to become 1D type
 End With
 
 lastCol = wsNew.cells(1, wsNew.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column
 arrN = wsNew.Range("A1", wsNew.cells(1, lastCol)).Value2
  With Application
    arrN = .Transpose(.Transpose(arrN)) 'the array to become 1D type
 End With
 
 Dim strMissing As String, i As Long
 For i = 1 To 2
    If i = 1 Then 'processing and returning for the Old sheet:
        arrMtch = Application.IfError(Application.match(arrO, arrN, 0), 0) 'it adds 0 instead of  not matching headers (returning error)
    Else 'processing and returning for the New sheet header:
        arrMtch = Application.IfError(Application.match(arrN, arrO, 0), 0)
    End If
    strMissing = "Missing from " & IIf(i = 1, "OldHeader", "NewHeader") & ":"
    Do
       mtch = Application.match(0, arrMtch, 0)
       If IsError(mtch) Then Exit Do
       strMissing = strMissing & vbCrLf & arrO(mtch)
       arrMtch(mtch) = "X" 'replacing 0, used only to match the missing match!
    Loop
    Debug.Print strMissing
    MsgBox strMissing
 Next i
End Sub
```

This was the principle/logic of working.

Here it is your adapted code:

```
Sub HeaderCompare2(ByVal oldWbPath As String, ByVal newWbPath As String)
    Dim wbOld As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
    Dim rngOld As Range, rngNew As Range, arrO, arrN, arrMtch, mtch

    Dim msg As String
    
    Set wbOld = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=oldWbPath)
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=newWbPath)
    
    Set rng1 = wbOld.Worksheets("TRAIN-D").Range("A1:BP1")
    Set rng2 = wbNew.Worksheets("TRAIN-D").Range("A1:BP1")
    arrO = rng1.Value2:  arrN = rng2.Value2
    
    With Application
       arrO = .Transpose(.Transpose(arrO)) 'to become 1D array
       arrN = .Transpose(.Transpose(arrN)) 'to become 1D array
    End With
    
    Dim strMissing As String, i As Long
    For i = 1 To 2
       If i = 1 Then
           arrMtch = Application.IfError(Application.match(arrO, arrN, 0), 0)
       Else
           arrMtch = Application.IfError(Application.match(arrN, arrO, 0), 0)
       End If
       strMissing = "Missing from " & IIf(i = 1, "OldHeader", "NewHeader") & ":"
       Do
          mtch = Application.match(0, arrMtch, 0)
          If IsError(mtch) Then Exit Do
          strMissing = strMissing & vbCrLf & arrO(mtch)
          arrMtch(mtch) = "X"
       Loop
       Debug.Print strMissing
       MsgBox strMissing
    Next i
End Sub
```

And your classic VBA code can be adapted in the next way:

```
Sub HeaderCompare2(ByVal oldWbPath As String, ByVal newWbPath As String)

    Dim wbOld As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
    Dim rngOld As Range, rngNew As Range, c As Range, mtch
    Dim msgOld As String, msgNew As String
    
    Set wbOld = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=oldWbPath)
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=newWbPath)
    
    Set rng1 = wbOld.Worksheets("TRAIN-D").Range("A1:BP1")
    Set rng2 = wbNew.Worksheets("TRAIN-D").Range("A1:BP1")
    
    msgOld = "Old Sheet Mismatch :"
    msgNew = "New Sheet Mismatch :"
    For Each c In rng1
        mtch = Application.match(c.Value, rng2, 0)
        If IsError(mtch) Then _
         msgOld = msgOld & vbCrLf & c.address & " Value " & c.Value
    Next rng1cell
    For Each rng2cell In rng2
        mtch = Application.match(c.Value, rng1, 0)
        If IsError(mtch) Then _
         msgNew = msgNew & vbCrLf & c.address & " Value " & c.Value
    Next rng2cell
    MsgBox msgOld & vbCrLf & msgNew

End Sub
```

Not tested the adaptations, but this should be a good logic and most probably they will work as it should.

If something not clear, do not hesitate to ask for clarification. If an error occurs, please mention what error and on which code line.

Comment: Thank you, your help is highly appreciated. However First and Second code returned empty MsgBox , For the last code , MsgBox returned  4 cell addresses which are empty cells. I think we are close to the solution.

Comment: @Hussein How did you set `wsOld` and `wsNew` in the first version (tested and working)? You can test it manually **opening the both involved workbooks**, then set each worksheet with reference to the workbook. Something like `Set wsOld = Workbooks("Your workbook name")`. **Not full name**! And similarly for the other one. Of course, the header **must be on the first row of each such worksheets**...

Comment: Afeter Closing the two workbooks and re-run the code the last code is working ok. but first and second still return empty msgbox

Comment: @Hussein Did you read my above comment? If so, did you declare the involved sheets as suggested? It would be a pity to not (correctly) try them. And learn something about arrays and how you can handle them... Without iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Your code try to compare each cell to each cell on the two sheets not only the corresponding ones. This is your edited code

```
Sub HeaderCompare2(ByVal oldWbPath As String, ByVal newWbPath As String)

Dim wbOld As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
    
Dim rngOld As Range, rngNew As Range, c As Range, FoundRange As Range

Dim msg As String

Set wbOld = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=oldWbPath)
Set wbNew = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=newWbPath)
Set ws = wbOld.Worksheets("TRAIN-D")             'this for shortening to refer the old sheet

Set rng1 = wbOld.Worksheets("TRAIN-D").Range("A1:BP1")
Set rng2 = wbNew.Worksheets("TRAIN-D").Range("A1:BP1")

Dim iRow As Integer
iRow = 1
' here this For loop is left out to avoid comparing each cell to one
    For Each rng2cell In rng2
        If ws.Range(rng2cell.Address) <> rng2cell Then
' the message box format adjusted            
            msg = msg & Chr(10) & rng2cell.Address & ": " & rng2cell & ";   " & ws.Range(rng2cell.Address)
            iRow = iRow + 1
        End If
    Next rng2cell
    

MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

The message box:
[image]

Comment: The code compare Sheet1.A1 to Sheet2.A1 &  Sheet1.B1 to Sheet2.B1 and so on. But this is not the point. The is to find values in header1 not in header 2 and vise versa regardless of order

Comment: Your question was about that `their headers (first rows) shoud be identical but`. Identical means in this context that corresponding cells has to be the same. @hussein

Comment: @ Black cat MAy be i was not clear enough. Appreciate your contribution anyway